# Suggestion for the appropriate control for a daily work schedule application in WPF and C#

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I am looking to create a Windows desktop application with WPF and C# that displays work shifts in a visual manner similar to http://www.shiftplanning.com/schedule/. So far, I've seen the Calendar control, but I really need a week displayed in an hour-by-hour layout. Can anyone suggest the appropriate control for the task? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look to [DevExpress scheduler](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/Scheduler/).
It's a paid option, but works great.